# How to update the android app when the Location toggle is enabled in Settings?

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, android-location

My app is promtping the user to switch on the Location service by navigating to Location-Settings activity.
Now how to check in the activity code when the user toggles the Location option in the settings activity.

```
public void checkGPS() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) GlobalHome.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    try {
        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
        // notify user
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GlobalHome.this);
        dialog.setMessage(MessagesString.LOCATION_DIALOG_MESSAGE);
        dialog.setPositiveButton(MessagesString.LOCATION_DIALOG_POSTIVE_TEXT, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                GlobalHome.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this , Hoping - it will solve your problem

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        isLocationServiceActive();

    }


    private void isLocationServiceActive(){

        locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationManager!=null){
            LocationProvider gpsLocationProvider=locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            LocationProvider networkLocationProvider=locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(gpsLocationProvider==null && networkLocationProvider==null){
                //device does'nt support location services
                showDeviceNotSupportLocationsDialog();
            }
            else if(networkLocationProvider!=null && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000L, 100.0F, this);

            }
            else if(gpsLocationProvider!=null && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){

                this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 100.0F, this);

            }
            else{
                showNoGpsDialog();
            }

        }


    }


    public void showNoGpsDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        localBuilder.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
        localBuilder.setPositiveButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS");
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(localIntent);
            }
        });
        localBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        localBuilder.show();
    }


    public void showDeviceNotSupportLocationsDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        localBuilder.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.device_not_support_locations));
        localBuilder.setPositiveButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.exit), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramAnonymousDialogInterface, int paramAnonymousInt)
            {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        localBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        localBuilder.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //location changed
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        //your code here

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        //your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        //your code here
    }



}
```

Comment: overridden methods onLocationChanged onProviderDisabled onStatusChanged are not getting invoked when I switch on the gps.

Comment: I am using startActivityForResult.
But is there a better way?

Comment: You need to check again after come back to your activity to ensure the status, is actually user has selected as ON location options, and if option is active then you can track with  onProviderDisabled onStatusChanged overriden methods

Comment: Agreed. But how to handle this case-user turns on gps from notification bar?

Comment: onProviderDisabled(String providerName) and  onProviderEnabled(String providerName) will be called when you activate or deactivate locations either from notifications or from setting

Comment: Why is onProviderEnabled() getting called twice?
Once for provider-gps and again for provider-network